# Firebase hosted app will not allow ios sign in via google, and not recognized certificate

Tags: firebase, web-hosting

I just completed the firebase codelab friendlychat tutorial, with hosting on firebase.

I can access it the app via a web browser on my laptop, but my iphone ios will not let me sign in via google. I also had to manually allow access to the site on my iphone as it said certificate was not valid.

https://.web.app

Can anyone tell me what is missing from the app, so far in testing mode, and the key concepts and key words so I can look up and learn about the issue.

Comment: everything worked once on my iPhone I manually allowed access to the google website as the certificate was not valid and 2 had to double tap to get buttons to work on my iPhone, whereas only a single click sufficed on the laptop browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you asking us what lines of code you've omitted from the app? That's going to be tough without seeing what lines of code you actually included first, right? Also, you may have missed a setup step in the Firebase console - or perhaps the authentication code is incorrect? Did you do any troubleshooting by stepping through your code? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Jay, as I followed through the tutorial using their code provided, it is hard to give you the kind of specifics you are asking for. I guess this is either something people have seen before in beginners or there is not much to say. I will explore things further and review authentication and hosting, coming at it afresh, in the next few days. Thanks